# Ту́пор. Этимология топонима

Tags: топонимика

Эта улица, хоть и на краю села (юго-западнее Пензы), не тупиковая. Уходит в поля, перешагивая через приток Сердобы, и становится «вылетной» грунтовой дорогой без имени, которой и упираться-то некуда, разве что прямо в небосвод... Как можно объяснить такое название?